# $4 \times 4$ Matrix Multiplication Equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I have three $4 \times 4$ matrices in the equation $A=XB$.
I want to find the matrix $X$.

What should I do ?

Comment: Multiply by B inverse then AB^(-1)=X

Comment: You can multiply the equation by $B^{-1}: AB^{-1}=XBB^{-1}\Rightarrow AB^{-1}=X$ ...$B^{-1}$ is the inverted matrix of $B$. $B$ must be invertible.

Comment: how do i know if B is invertible ?

Comment: The columns (rows) have to be linearly independent. This can be evaluated by calculating the determinant. If $det \ B\neq 0$, then the columns are linearly Independent and $B$ can be inverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that B is an invertible matrix, then you multiply on the right by $B^{-1}$:

$$AB^{-1} = XBB^{-1}= X $$